# Distinguishing Tag and Category names in SQL query replace

Tags: sql, wordpress

I use this command in SQL to replace a TAG name into another language. The tag names changes from 'pattern' to 'motif':

```
UPDATE wp_terms
SET name =
REPLACE(
name,
'pattern',
'motif')
WHERE term_group LIKE '0'
```

But I also have a category name called "pattern", which i do not want to be renamed to "motif". The above command would rename the tag as well as the category name. How can I pinpoint the query to only rename tags, and not the categories? As I understand both tags and categories are located in wp_terms.

In phpMyadmin wp_terms only have the columns: term_id, name, slug, term_group. 
However, I did see there is one way to possibly achieve it. The 'name' of the tags, have the same value as the 'slug' column.

Is there a way to modify the SQL query to something like:

```
UPDATE wp_terms
    SET name =
    REPLACE(
    name,
    'pattern',
    'motif')
    WHERE 'slug' IS THE SAME AS 'name' COLUMN
```

I'm not sure how to modify my SQL query correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding another condition:

```
UPDATE
      WP_TERMS
SET
      NAME      =
          REPLACE ( NAME,
                  'pattern',
                  'motif' )
WHERE
      TERM_GROUP LIKE '0'
      AND NAME = SLUG;
```

Comment: In wp_terms there's no 'taxonomy' column so the query does not work. It only has term_id, name, slug, term_group. However, I did see there is one way to possibly achieve it.  The 'name' of the tags, have the same value as the 'slug' column.  Is there a way to modify the SQL query to something like:   REPLACE name WHERE slug IS SAME value as NAME

Comment: Please post your table structures and mention the columns relation and the values to be updated

Comment: Here is the table structure:  http://i.imgur.com/R01rxqq.png   As you can see, there's a tag called pattern, and also a category called pattern. So to only change the tag name, perhaps the rule can be that only make the change IF the slug is the same value as the name,  then it would work.